# If you can go lower level than TCP in the browser

Tags: networking, browser, tcp, ip, ethernet

I am learning about [Network Protocols](https://wiki.osdev.org/Network_Stack#Networking_protocols), and see that near the lowest level is the raw ethernet protocol:

> Ethernet: this is the basic protocol that sends data to another machine on your local network using your MAC address. This is the building block for all the rest as you need to send data to the router if you want to communicate with the outside world.

Above that is the Internet Protocol (IP), of which TCP and UDP are examples. On top of TCP is HTTP, or SSL on top of which you can put HTTP (so HTTPS).

It seems that the browser only lets you go down to the level of the IP (TCP for your normal message passing connections, and UDP for things like video). But I'm wondering, if it's possible to go any lower than that in the browser. If not, then wondering why not. If so, then what an example might be.

Comment: "_Above that is the Internet Protocol (IP), of which TCP and UDP are examples._" That is incorrect. There are currently two IPs (Internet Protocols): IPv4 and IPv6. IP is a network-layer protocol. TCP and UDP are two (of many) transport-layer protocols, which operate above the network layer. You browser speak HTML to the HTTP application-layer protocol, and it doesn't involve itself with any lower-level protocols. The beauty of the layers is that you can replace a protocol in one layer, and the other layers don't' need to know. For example, IPv6 for IPv4, or TCP on IPX.

Comment: And re your title, you can't even go below HTTP, let alone TCP. You can go *beside* HTTP, by using FTP for example,, but you can't even access TCP directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> “It seems that the browser only lets you go down to the level of the
>   IP (TCP for your normal message passing connections, and UDP for
>   things like video).”

Firstly TCP and UDP are **not** examples of IP. They are **Transport** layer protocols, which is a layer above IP.

This representation of the 5 layer model should help make the distinction:

[image: 5 Layer Networking Model]

- Secondly, if by *'go down to the level of Ethernet’* you mean inspect packets with your browser’s dev tools, you can’t do that. You can only see HTTP packets.

If you want to observe all traffic, you can use tools like [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/) - or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)  to capture and inspect packets across the different layers.

- If you are asking if the browser can use any layers other than the *Application Layer*. No, it cannot. That's also why you can only observe HTTP packets, because that's the layer which the browser operates on.

Information travels from layer to layer, but doesn't skip layers:

[image: How packets travels through the TCP/IP stack from the sending host]

Your request for a web page uses **all the layers**. It starts at the application layer, which is the user-facing layer, all the way down the stack until the Network layer transports your requests to the server's Network layer, where it goes up the stack to fetch the web page.

> The packet is the basic unit of information that is transferred across
>   a network. The packet consists, at a minimum, of a header with the
>   sending and receiving hosts' addresses, and a body with the data to be
>   transferred. As the packet travels through the TCP/IP protocol stack,
>   the protocols at each layer either add or remove fields from the basic
>   header. When a protocol on the sending host adds data to the packet
>   header, the process is called data encapsulation. Moreover, each layer
>   has a different term for the altered packet, as shown in the following
>   figure.

You can read more about the way packets travel across the protocol stack in this article about [Data Encapsulation and the TCP/IP Protocol Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4075/ipov-32/)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers only allow to use a well-defined set of protocols due to security reasons. If this wouldn't be the case, Javascript on websites could send send arbitrary packets and cause malicious behavior.

Therefore the browser APIs are limited to make only HTTP, websockets and webrtc available.

Answer (score 0):

In good old days (until about 3 years ago) browsers solved that problem by allowing to run a 3-rd party plugin, and there were (and there are still are) APIs for these plugins, such as NPAPI and ActiveX control. So you could create a plugin that does anything you want, send data with raw sockets or your own protocol. Flash plugin is the best example, and there are numerous less known ones, used in specific web applications, such as web conferencing, chat, secure data exchange etc... Some browsers still support these plugins - IE, Opera, Firefox, but Chrome and Edge completely disabled them. The reason is security issues - if you can load your own native code into browser then you can have a full access to OS, intercept all data in the browser, etc... As a replacement for this disabled freedom, some browsers tried to invent new more safe APIs such as PPAPI of Chrome. Mostly a failed attempt. Browser's adoption of websockets mitigated the situation, but still, lots of networking things are not possible in the browser. One notorious example is the lack of UDP Multicast support in browsers. Previously you could do it with your own NPAPI plugin; now no replacement is offered by browsers, so your browser-based multicast-involved applications are dead.